# Splitting list of words and definitions into two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a list of words such as:

```
ventana - window
puerta - door
silla - chair
```

Now, I need to split this into two arrays:

```
var words = ['ventana','puerta','silla'];
var defs = ['window','door','chair'];
```

I guess I could split the string at the line breaks, then take the new array and split that at every ' - '. But I'm not sure exactly how to do this. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code so far? What went wrong?

Comment: Note: to format a block of code indent by four spaces, or select the relevant block and click the `{}` button above the edit window. Only use ` for code that you want to show inline in a sentence `like this`.

Comment: You already know the logic. All you need is some code. Why dont you try something to start with and we will help you from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I guess I could split the string at the line breaks, then take the new array and split that at every ' - '"*

Yes, that would work fine, if you mean "take the new array and split" each item in it. Assuming you're starting with those words as a string:

```
var list = 'ventana - window\npuerta - door\nsilla - chair';
```

Then proceed as follows:

```
var pairs = list.split('\n'),
    words = [],
    defs = [],
    i, tmp;
for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    tmp = pairs[i].split(' - ');
    words.push(tmp[0]);
    defs.push(tmp[1]);
}
```

Note that this code does no error checking to be sure that the substrings between each newline character actually do have a pair of words separated by `' - '`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you...

Answer (score 1):

The obvious algorithm will be splitting the string in newlines and iterating for each line, splitting it again with the separator character.

However, a more optimized version of it could be (assuming that the input value is well-formatted):

```
 var dic = str.split(/[\n\-]/);
 var pos = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < dic.length; i++) {
     words[pos] = dic[i];
     dic[pos] = defs[++i];
 }
```

One single loop, one single call to "split", no recursion and no abuse of function calls.

NOTE: I haven't tried the code, is just a concept. Nevertheless, the question **should provide what have you tried so far**.

Comment: +1. I like this concept. Though I think `/\n| - /` is the regex you'd need. (And I don't really like that you change the loop counter inside the loop - for a for loop I'd prefer `defs[i+1]` and `i+=2` after each iteration.) But still, as I said, +1.

Comment: Well, we actually don't have the real string declared, but I believe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringYouHave = "ventana - window puerta - door silla - chair";
function getKVPairs(str){
    var a = str.split(" ");
    return a;
}
var kvPairs = getKVPairs(stringYouHave);
var defs= new Array();
var words = new Array();
for(var i = 0 ; i < kvPairs.length;i++){
    var a = kvPairs[i].split("-");
    words.push(a[0]);
    defs.push(a[1]);
}
console.log(words);
console.log(defs);
```

This is how you may do that.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use method like [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
// assuming `s` is the string

var dict = s.split(/\n/)
            .reduce(function(dict, item) { 
                var terms = item.split(/ - /);

                dict.words.push(terms[0]);
                dict.defs.push(terms[1]);

                return dict;
            }, {words:[], defs:[]});
```